# git push permission denied

Tags: permissions, git

I have a `Ubuntu 18.0.4` vm, I wanted to push my code to git that I created in gitlab.

**What I already done**

1. Install git
2. created ssh-key
3. added my ssh-key to gitlab
4. create repository in gitlab
5. git init
6. git remote add origin the_git_link
7. sudo git add .
8. sudo git commit -m "msg"

**What I stucked**

1. sudo git push origin master

**Error Message from Ubuntu terminal**

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Why are you using git with sudo?

Comment: because it say permission denied, Im new, I only know sudo

Comment: @Pilot6 any suggest solution ?

Comment: I found a solution [fix permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564078/4401349)